# Flash builder read-only rich text field?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, richtextbox, mxml

How is it possible to DISPLAY text with simple formatting (like font color) in flash `TextArea` or similar control? I need to add text to this control programmatically and be able to select and copy portions of it to clipboard.

`RichTextEditor` does not fit my needs sine it has multiple controls to allow user to format text and no way to disable them (?).

**UPDATE**

Additional question is how to code formatting. Only `<b>` does work in the following code:

```
private function Print(s:String, ... optionalArgs):void {
            if( optionalArgs.length == 0 || optionalArgs[0]==0) {
                mLog.htmlText = mLog.htmlText + '<b>' + s + '</b><br>';
            }
            else if(optionalArgs[0]==-1) {
                mLog.htmlText = mLog.htmlText + '<font color=\"red\">' + s + '</font><br>';
            }
            else if(optionalArgs[0]==1) {
                mLog.htmlText = mLog.htmlText + '<span style=\"color:green\">' + s + '</span><br>';
            }
            else if(optionalArgs[0]==2) {
                mLog.htmlText = mLog.htmlText + '<span style=\"color:blue\">' + s + '</span><br>';
            }
            else {
                mLog.htmlText = mLog.htmlText + '<b>' + s + '</b><br>';
            }
        }
```

How to code font color?

**SOLUTION**

My mistake was I was using symbolic color names, while flash interpreter looks like do not understand them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a very easy problem to solve. `RichTextEditor` has a `showControlBar` setting, which if set to `false`, hides the fancy controls.

Also, you can access the internal text area and make it uneditable (`myRTE.textArea.editable= false`), restricting user interaction with the text.

Synopsis:

```
<mx:RichTextEditor id="myRTE" showControlBar="false"... />

...

myRTE.textArea.editable = false;
```

---

Here's a few resources for formatting your `htmlText`: [Adobe 'RichTextEditor Control'](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_10.html), [Adobe 'using htmlText properly'](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html#439608)

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to put RTF or HTML into this control?

Comment: @Dims I added a few links that should help you out with formatting.